# eXist-db size limit

Tags: http-put, exist-db

I'm trying to upload a file to eXist-db using a PUT request and am getting the following message:

```
500 Server Error: Form too large 392430>200000
```

How can I override this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on the exist-open mailing list at http://markmail.org/message/njpvhheytnlhiidu.